# How to read powershell manifest file (.psd1) using c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to access manifest details for a custom PowerShell module that has the manifest file stored along with the module(psm1) file in my directory structure.

What is the best way to access the manifest details like Description, GUID etc?

Comment: Most lines are in form of key = value, so just read the file and filter out everything but the lines that look like that, perhaps with regex and then load the values that you need. That should be it. Do you have any specific problem in accomplishing what you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A psd1 file is a valid PowerShell script, so it's best to let PowerShell parse the file.

The simplest way is to use the Test-ModuleManifest cmdlet.  From C#, that would look something like:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddCommand("Test-ModuleManifest").AddParameter("Path", manifestPath);
    var result = ps.Invoke();
    PSModuleInfo moduleInfo = result[0].BaseObject as PSModuleInfo;

    // now you can look at the properties like Guid or Description
}
```

Other approaches cannot handle the complexities of parsing PowerShell, e.g. it would be easy to incorrectly handle comments or here strings when trying to use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to `System.Management.Automation`. Then, use the following code to get a `Hashtable` from the `.psd1` file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    string psd = "C:\\Users\\Trevor\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules\\ISESteroids\\ISESteroids.psd1";
    ps.AddScript(String.Format("Invoke-Expression -Command (Get-Content -Path \"{0}\" -Raw)", psd));
    var result = ps.Invoke();
    Debug.WriteLine(((Hashtable)result[0].ImmediateBaseObject)["Description"]);
}
```

Comment: Note that this method is dangerous if you don't trust the input - Invoke-Expression will happily run whatever you have in the psd1 file, e.g. it might not be a hashtable (PowerShell wouldn't load the module, but this sample ignores that.)